# If $\omega^3 =1$ then how is $\omega^5=(\omega^{3})^{5/3}=1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

While revising the chapter complex number, when i was reading the the concept of the cube roots of unity, I read $\omega^3=1$, where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity other than 1, then $\omega ^5=\omega^3.\omega^2=\omega^2(\because\omega^3=1)$

the above thing is we all know, is correct, but you see i don't know how my brain functioned and i thought that $$\omega^5=(\omega^3)^{\frac 53}=(1)^\frac 53=1 \{\because \omega^3=1\}$$

but you know, this is wrong, i don't know how this wrong but i can see this to be wrong because if this true then $\omega ^k=1, k\in R$.

**So how  $$\omega^5=(\omega^3)^{\frac 53}=(1)^\frac 53=1 $$ is wrong? what are the wrong assumptions which is taken by me while writing that statement**?

Comment: It's usually helpful in such cases to work with complex exponentials. To that end, suppose we take $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ as our cubic root of unity. Then your reasoning can be stated as: $$(e^{2\pi i/3})^5 = (e^{2\pi i})^{5/3} = (e^{0})^{5/3}=e^0.$$

Comment: Note that if $\omega^3=1$ then $\omega^5=\omega^2\omega^3=\omega^21=\omega^2$ but $\omega^{-1}=\omega^2$ and $\omega^{-1}=1$ if and only if $\omega=1$.

Comment: You can do the same with the square root of $1$ other than $1$ (that is, $-1$): $$\omega = -1 \implies \omega^2 = 1 \implies \omega^3 = (\omega^2)^{2/3} = 1^{2/3} = 1$$ but on the other hand $$\omega^3 = \omega^2\cdot\omega = 1\cdot\omega = \omega=-1$$

Comment: FYI, the step $$(1)^{5/3}=1 $$ is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrong assumption lies in the step where you write:

> $$\omega^5=(\omega^3)^\frac{5}{3}$$

This is wrong since it assumes the existence of a mapping $u$ similar to the power $t↦t^\frac35$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ in the sense that
$u(z^5)=z^3$
for every $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Such a mapping $u$ does not exist eventhough $u$ does exist on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So... the wrong step is not the (true) identity $$1^{5/3}=1$$ but the identity $$\omega^3=(\omega^5)^{5/3}$$ which posits the existence of a mapping $u$ similar to the power $t\mapsto t^{3/5}$ on $\mathbb R_+$ in the sense that $$u(z^5)=z^3$$ for every $z$ in $\mathbb C$. Such a mapping $u$ does not exist (note that $u$ does exist on $\mathbb R$...).

Comment: @Did I agree with you in the second part but for the first part, I think it is not an identity (it is valid only for reals). It is equivalent to solving $x^3=1$ and $1$ is only the real solution. The complex solutions are still lying there.

Comment: In a way, you are making the same mistake as in the second part, only reversed: $1^{5/3}$ is well defined and is equal to $1$ because there exists a canonical function $u:t\mapsto t^{5/3}$ defined on $\mathbb R_+$ and because $1$ is in $\mathbb R_+$.

Comment: @Did Okay, finally I got your point. I have corrected my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This is of course wrong. The rule you forgot is the use of rational exponents is valid *only for real positive numbers*.

An illuminating example is the following: consider the cube root of $-8$. You might want to write is as $(-8)^{1/3}=-2$.

However, since $1/3=2/6$, it would also be $\bigl((-8)^2\bigr)^{1/6}=64^{1/6}=+2$, or even $\bigl((-8)^{1/6}\bigr)^2$, and the sixth root of $-8$ doesn't even exist, in the real numbers. Of course, in the complex numbers, $-8$ has sixth roots – but it has six of them!

Here, the simplest thing to do is to use this fact: the non-real cubic roots of unity generate a cyclic group of order $3$, so $\;\omega^5=\omega^2\; (=\mkern1mu\overline{\mkern-1mu\omega\mkern-1mu}\mkern1mu=\omega^{-1})$.